# How to rediret to specific page depends upon user roles

Tags: ajax, users

I have 2 user roles. When a user logs in, I want to redirect the user to a specific page based on their role. I tried the Login_destination module, but it has not worked for me. I have also tried using the trigger action, but it has also not helped me. When I used this trigger action, the ajax module threw an unexpected error message.. SO please help me.. How do I solve this problem...

Comment: I haven't got time to write a proper, in depth answer sorry, but try the rules module. It should be able to do that.

Comment: Hey rooby, i am use the rules module i did it.. but one problem is their , when user directly enter the redirected page path then it not restricted..this page is open so how solve this issue. will u give me solution about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with rules
You can try the following

1. Create a rule with event as "User has logged in".
2. Add condition "User has role(s)" and configure it as in screenshot[image]
3. Then save the condition.
4. Now add action to you rule and select "page redirect" under system in the select the action to add dropdown.
5. This will open a form which will allow you to set the redirection path, simply in the value field give the internal page path you want the user to be redirected to and then save it.Check the screenshot for better understanding
   [image]
   This way you can set redirect for one role and similarly you can create one more rule in a similar way for the other user role, if you want the other role to redirect to some other page.

Comment: i installed rule module but not display in menus of admin... !

Comment: arpitr:- this write answer for drupal 7, but i am using drupal 6 will u give me solution for d6.

Comment: did you enable rules ui module, if not please enable the rules ui module then you can see the rules under configuration.Mahi I need to check on d6, I didn get time I'll update you once I review it on d6,